# CMD Prompt: Allow/Block a SERVICE in Windows Firewall... how to?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, windows-firewall

Does anyone know the **Command Prompt** syntax to Allow/Block a **Windows Service** in **Windows Firewall**?

Research hasn't turned up a certain answer, even from Microsoft's official site.

Specifying *services* here, not programs.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft, it seems that we can only use CMD to Allow/Block the specified two services.

(1)File and Printer Sharing
(2)Remote Desktop

If I take any mistakes, please correct me.